# Event not showing in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using http://fullcalendar.io/ for displaying calendar events in my application. But now I have encountered an unexpected behaviour in it. Events are not displaying in the day box, but it is correctly displaying in the **more** link. I don't know how to explain it, so I have attached a screenshot.

> For dates 30,31,1,2,3 there are some events for that date. But no
>   events is been showing in the calendar date. But if you click the more
>   link all events are been showing correctly.

[image]

---

[image]
Have anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: that is the updated fullcalendar. it shows it in the more link cause u have too mutch elements on that day (Mostly at month view)

Comment: The plugin calculates how many elements fits inside the box including the `more` link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601021/fullcalendar-limit-number-of-events-and-have-a-more-link

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude i think there is some error in the calculation. If you notice the dates 30,31,1, 2, 3 there are some events for that dates, but in the view no event is showing.

Comment: Maybe, I've had this problem too about 3 or 4 months ago, and the problem was that events are too long and the plugin makes the calculations *comme ci comme ça*

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Have you found any workaround for this?

Comment: Yes, I define a CSS with `text-overflow` to make the events only one line, and I reduce the size of the text and the plugin make the same calculations but with different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is the desired behavior of full calendar. After much time think i understood the issue. ie. once an event is been showed in the more menu, it will always be displayed in the more menu evenif there is space in other days.

If we consider an event spanning from January 10 - January 25, if the event is in the more menu for January 10, it will always be in the more menu. But if we show the event from January 15 (bcoz there is space) in the date box, it will make an impression as the event is starting from that date.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the 2.5.0 fullcalendar version ?

I'm using the 2.4.0 and I made few tests with the param like you seems to be configured

```
eventLimit: "true",
eventLimitClick:"popover",
```

It's works for me. "More links" and popover are working.

Maybe it's a version bug ?